# look up dictionary in python

Tags: python

So I have file that with multiple line that look like this (space delimiter file):

```
A1BG      P04217     VAR_018369  p.His52Arg     Polymorphism  rs893184    -
A1BG      P04217     VAR_018370  p.His395Arg    Polymorphism  rs2241788   -
AAAS      Q9NRG9     VAR_012804  p.Gln15Lys     Disease       -           Achalasia
```

How do I make dictionary to look for id in second column and store the number (between words) on fourth column.

I tried this but it give me index of out range

```
lookup = defaultdict(list)
with open ('humsavar.txt', 'r') as humsavarTxt:
    for line in csv.reader(humsavarTxt):
        code = re.match('[a-z](\d+)[a-z]', line[1], re.I)
        if code: 
            lookup[line[-2]].append(code.group(1))

print lookup['P04217']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a variant of the original code:

```
import csv, re
from collections import defaultdict

lookup = defaultdict(list)
with open('humsavar.txt', 'rb') as humsavarTxt:
    reader = csv.reader(humsavarTxt, delimiter=" ", skipinitialspace=True)
    for line in reader:
        code = re.search(r'(\d+)', line[3])
        lookup[line[1]].append(int(code.group(1)))
```

which produces

```
>>> lookup
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'P04217': [52, 395], 'Q9NRG9': [15]})
>>> lookup['P04217']
[52, 395]
```

Comment: thanks.. if i make this into a method do i just add def method_lookup(id) and add return in front of lookup?

Comment: Yes, add `return lookup[id]` after the last line, outside the for-loop of course.
(Although there is a more efficient way to do this if you just want one id: search for the correct line, and only process that line. But for small files making a dict is much simpler, so you should probably stick to that!)

Comment: @BrtH what other way do you suggest i have a large file

Comment: @ChadD: If large means much more than 100.000 lines, than I would get into the effort of coming up with a more efficient way, but I doubt that your file is that large.

Answer (score 1):

If the id and the number is always in the second and fourth column, and it's always space delimited you don't need to use regular expresion. You can split on the spaces instead:

```
lookup = defaultdict(list)
with open ('humsavar.txt', 'r') as humsavarTxt:
    for line in humsavarTxt:
         lookup[line.split(' ')[1]].append(line.split(' ')[3])
```

Comment: `line.split(' ')` will turn `"a[space][space]b"` into `['a', '', 'b']`.  Simply use `line.split()`.

Comment: @DSM thanks.. do you know why it only yield 1 result since id P04217 has two line and it should return 2  results

Comment: @ChadD: your code uses a `defaultdict` and appends, so you get a list.  This code simply reassigns to the dictionary, so the second line of your file will replace the first line's data.

Comment: @ChadD: What DSM says, I edited this answer a bit to show it with the defaultdict.

Comment: @DSM so what is wrong with my code? I am not very clear about where to put append. Could you please show me ? thanks

Comment: @ChadD, wait a few minutes untill my edit is approved, and you will see it in Niek de Klein's answer.

Comment: @BrtH thanks.. so my list corresponding to id will be only number correct no letters. for example, [52, 392] for id P04217... thanks again

Comment: @ChadD, what do you mean? `lookup['P04217']` returns `['p.His52Arg', 'p.His395Arg']` for me. Is this what you want, or do you want it to be `[52, 392]`? Please clarify, 'cause if you need some more modifications to this code I will consider to make my own answer.

Comment: @BrtH yes i want only number in the list [52, 392] for lookup['P04217']. thanks

Comment: I was already busy making my answer, but @DSM beat me to it. His way is indead the way to go.

Comment: @BrtH: ah, sorry, man.  :-/  When I realized that the accepted answer didn't quite work I figured I should add one that did..

Comment: @DSM: No problem, I hadn't thought about the csv module, so your answer is better anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a pure dictionary, this works:

```
d={}
with open(your_file,'rb') as f:
    for line in f:
        l=line.split()
        num=int(re.search(r'(\d+)',l[3]).group(1))
        d.setdefault(l[1],[]).append(num)
```

Prints:

```
{'P04217': [52, 395], 'Q9NRG9': [15]}
```

For a non regex solution, you can also do this:

```
d={}
with open(your_file,'rb') as f:
    for line in f:
        els=line.split()
        num=int(''.join(c for c in els[3] if c.isdigit()))
        d.setdefault(els[1],[]).append(num)
```

Comment: It is the regex for 1 or more digits